# I can't see my USB?

Tags: 12.04, usb

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04, and I'm new to this OS. My problem is that when I plug in my USB I can't see it alongside the drivers. Can anyone help?

I used command `sudo fdisk -l` and the result is:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 319.9 GB, 319936615424 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38896 cylinders, total 624876202 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xf0feae57

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *      206848   124985343    62389248    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       124985761   624864239   249939239+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda4       618212010   624876201     3332096    0  Empty
/dev/sda5       124985763   249971399    62492818+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       374957163   499942799    62492818+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       499942863   624864239    62460688+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda8       249972736   318330879    34179072   83  Linux
/dev/sda9       318332928   374943743    28305408   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 4043 MB, 4043309056 bytes
125 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1018 cylinders, total 7897088 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x6f20736b
This doesn't look like a partition table
Probably you selected the wrong device.

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   ?   778135908  1919645538   570754815+  72  Unknown
/dev/sdb2   ?   168689522  2104717761   968014120   65  Novell Netware 386
/dev/sdb3   ?  1869881465  3805909656   968014096   79  Unknown
/dev/sdb4   ?  2885681152  2885736650       27749+   d  Unknown

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Comment: After you plug in your USB, open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and issue this command `lsusb` . Edit your question and add more info please. What is this usb ? An HDD or a Stick ? of maybe a wireless USB ? what ?

Comment: Bus 001 Device 002: ID 125f:c83a A-DATA Technology Co., Ltd.(A-data is my usb but how can i see it's content or format it)

Comment: So, this is a USB Flash Drive. What about the formating ? Check this command also `sudo fdisk -l` is your USB flash listed there ? Please edit your question and add the results. Full results. Not in comments.

Comment: I had a very similar problem to this. Tthe USB disk was recognized (through say `lsusb` and `sudo fdisk -l`) but no mount point showing. The problem was that the USB had been formatted with **no partition**. By opening the `Disks` utility you can easily make a partition (there are different types - FAT, NTFS etc.), and the USB will have a file system to mount to; no problemo!